# Why Properties pane in Visual Studio 2022 Community is empty?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am not sure why I cannot open properties pane in visual studio 2022 Community version installed on my Windows 11. I have attempted multiple approaches but still having to deal with a blank page in properties pane. I need help from community,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open a `Console Application` instead of `CMakeProject` or `Windows Desktop Application` in the start of the Visual Studio. For some reason that I don't understand, CMakeProject or Windows Desktop Application templates are not allowing to have an active "properties" pane for the project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a file in order to view the properties. In the screenshot you attached; you have not opened any files.

Comment: as you can see  in the upper center of the menu, there is name of the file. The tabs are just closed. Otherwise, I have tried it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You have opened the project. But you need to open the files as tabs. So that the properties pane will preview the properties.

Comment: Added new screen shots.

Comment: Have the Solution Explorer pane and Properties pane pinned. Click on the file you need view the properties. Eg. CMakeList.txt.

Comment: I have tried everything you are mentioning with no success.

Comment: Sorry for your bad experience. I tried to replicate the issue from my end. But it works fine for me. Perhaps re-installing the VS might help.

Answer (score 0):

try to reset window layout.

Go to the "Window" menu and select "Reset Window Layout" to reset the layout of Visual Studio to its default state. This can sometimes fix issues with the properties pane.

Comment: Tried with no success but thank you.